# Error while trying to install php module for apache2

Tags: php, apache

Initially the problem was PHP files on my server were displayed as plain text(the whole code was shown). So I found out by investigating that the MIME type has to be added to the `/etc/mime.types` , so I did that and also restarted my server but that didn't help solve the issue so on further investigation, I found out from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/393339/apache-shows-html-php-files-as-txt) that we needed php5 module enabled and on running the `apachectl -M`, I couldn't find the php5 module listed. So I tried installing it and this was the outcome of it :

```
admin@vm:~$ sudo apt-get install php5
...
php5_invoke pdo: already enabled for apache2 SAPI
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

admin@vm:~$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also need to mention that I created 2 virtual hosts for the sites. I am not sure what is wrong. Could some one help me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a proper solution but I re-installed Apache and it worked fine:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge apache2 
$ sudo apt-get purge php5 libapache2-mod-php5 
$ sudo apt-get purge autoremove 
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

Comment: $ sudo apt-get purge autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package autoremove

Comment: autoremove should not have "purge"

Answer (score 0):

the package libapache2-mod-php5 comprise libphp5.so which locates  at /usr/lib/apache2/modules, and php5.conf/php5.load which locate at /etc/apache2/mods-availables.
thus you could get the three files, and copy to corresponding position.
And, you should link, using ln -s, php5.conf/load to /etc/apache2/mods-enables, thus apached could find the configuration file and load the libphp5.so.

I got the same problem and resolve it